# how to get the hours of the day, when hours is column to row in sql?

Tags: sql

I have this data in my table:

```
Class         Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
--------------------------------------------------------------------
class 1       8:00    12:00    8:00       8:00      10:00
class 2       7:00    15:00    7:00       NULL      7:00
class 3       11:00   11:00    12:00      NULL      NULL
```

And I need to get the information as follows

```
Class         Day        Hour
--------------------------------------------------------------------
class 1       Monday      8:00
class 1       Tuesday    12:00
class 1       Wednesday   8:00
class 1       Thursday    8:00
class 1       Friday     10:00

class 2       Monday      7:00
class 2       Tuesday    15:00
class 2       Wednesday   7:00
class 2       Friday      7:00

class 3       Monday     11:00
class 3       Tuesday    11:00
class 3       Wednesday  12:00
```

Thanks for your answers and help guys, I really appreciate

Note: the result of the query will be displayed in an excel

Comment: Shouldn’t you do that in the presentation layer? It’s very simple there, no reason to do it in the database. And you didn’t mention which one.

Comment: Depending on your platform there should be some form of PIVOT functionality.  If this is for a report you can also look at the presentation tool to do this instead.  For example SSRS matrix can do this with very little work to setup.

Comment: It is not for use in programming code, it is to be displayed in an excel

Comment: As the first 2 commenters have put together; this should be done in the presentation layer utilizing PIVOT functionality. There is plenty of documentation on how to do this in Excel, which you state is the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an operation called UNPIVOT, which rotates columns to rows. You can produce the result you want with a query like this one, assuming you are using SQL Server:

```
SELECT Class, Day, Hour
FROM classes UNPIVOT (Hour FOR Day IN (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)) u
```

Answer (score 0):

Select *
From table 
Order by Class, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday